# Whether to store and retrieve data from a javascript object or a backend database

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm a novice programmer and in the process of building one of my first web apps using Node and Express, while connected to a MongoDB database.

For part of my app the user enters values into a form, and in one part selects from a list of 30 possible Door types.  Upon submitting the form, the Door type is queried in my database, which is pre-loaded, and the Weight value for that Door type is retrieved.  Then the Weight value is used to do a calculation with two other values (height and width) submitted in the form.  I got this to work using callback functions when the form is posted.

My question is:  would this type of process be simpler if I just stored the weights of the different door types in a Javascript object and then retrieve the proper weight using dot notation?  The doors only have three properties: name, weight, and one other.  This way I don't have to take the time to query the database.  Any suggestions for the best way to do this process?

Comment: In my experience, data should always be a service, ie, you should separate your data from your application (in a database). This makes it easier to scale your application when needed.  If you are 100% certain that your data will not change, you can hardcode it but its bad practice.

Comment: doing it as a JS object would be much faster for the user, easier on device batteries and mobile data plans, puts less traffic on your server, is far simpler in general, and operates during wifi outages...

Comment: as a compromise, you can cache the data in javascript and validate with the service for any changes, so that you can easily modify data when need arises and the performance/load is managed efficiently.

Comment: very insightful comments, thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mongodb is largely used for databases where there lot of documents and few relationship. Your type of application will do better with Mongodb as it is easily scalable. Also simple math operations while storing and retrieving documents can be performed using [these](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) in-built functions.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and the link!